# ObjectMapper enable method is deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I'm upgrading the version of my project and I am currently using jackson-databind-2.13.0
.But I noticed that ObjectMapper's enable method is deprecated.

They said to use it like this instead.

```
@deprecated Since 2.13 use {@code JsonMapper.builder().enable(...)}
```

But I couldn't use it.

Below is my ObjectMapper instance creation code. how can I change?

```
      @Bean(name = {"objectMapper"})
      @Primary
      ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return newObjectMapper();
      }

  public static ObjectMapper newObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper =
        new ObjectMapper()
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);
JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
javaTimeModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeSerializer());
javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeDeserializer());
javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
objectMapper
    .registerModule(javaTimeModule)
    .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

return objectMapper;
```

}

Solution:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper
    .builder()
    .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
    .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
    .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
    .serializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL).build();
```

Comment: Why couldn't you use it? Did you get an error? Was the result unexpected? The deprecation comment pretty clearer states that `new ObjectMapper().enable(…)` should be converted to `JsonMapper.builder().enable(…).build()`

Comment: Why aren't you using the Spring Boot configured instance and let Spring Boot configure it (and you provide some properties to configure it as you want?

Comment: being deprecated doesn't mean you can't use it, it means you shouldn't use it. As in: yes, you can still use it now, but you should refactor your code before the method is removed from a new(er) version of the library

Comment: I actually use it, I don't get any errors. I just want to change.

Comment: You are using what? This method or the Spring Boot configured one (as that you aren't as you are configuring it yourself).

Comment: how can i use JsonMapper.builder().enable(...) instead of .enable(..)
There are no examples in the jackson-databind docs. I want to change something that is deprecated.

Comment: @SezerAydın this might be me not understanding you, but the answer to "how can I use `JsonMapper.builder().enable(…)`" is "you use `JsonMapper.builder().enable(…)`". You replace the old code with the new code, as instructed by the deprecation note. The JavaDoc or your IDE's auto-completion will help you know which methods are available on the builder instance (I assume most methods will have identical names to make migration easy).

Comment: I misspelled the first comment. currently, I am not using JsonMapper. Therefore, I do not use its methods.
Now let me explain the other part. I am using enable(..) method of objectmapper.
and this method has been deprecated after version 2.13. And yes you are right i can use this method. but i dont want to use.  I will use the JsonMapper.builder.enable(..) method as stated in the documentation.

Comment: i've added my ObjectMapperConfiguration class

Comment: @SezerAydın I still don't understand your question. You replace `new ObjectMapper().enable(…)` with `JsonMapper.builder().enable(…).build()`. What exactly is your problem with the new code? Errors, exceptions, unexpected results?

Comment: My fault, I didn't look carefully.
The JsonMapper class is being extended from ObjectMapper.

Comment: Thank you all and @knittl. I've added solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest to rewrite your code to either

1. Remove this bean and use a fully Spring Boot configured `ObjectMapper` (which has the name `jacksonObjectMapper`)
2. Use the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` to create an instance of the `ObjectMapper`.

All of these solutions hide the intricate parts of constructing the `ObjectMapper` and will also put the burden of constructing it (properly) on the Spring Boot team, instead of you.

Now for option 1 you would need to remove your `@Bean` and place the following in your `application.properties`.

```
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false

spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=false
spring.jackson.deserialization.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY=true

spring.jackson.mapper.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES=true

spring.jackson.defaultPropertyInclusion=NON_NULL
```

When Spring (Boot) detects the `JavaTime` module on the classpath it will automatically be registered with the `ObjectMapper`, so no need to additionally add that (or the serializers for that matter).

These lines of configuration should you give the same configured `ObjectMapper` as your explicitly configured one. H

For the second option you can inject the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` into the method by using an argument, configure the things you want on there and call the `build` method in the end.

```java
@Bean(name = {"objectMapper"})
@Primary
ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    return newObjectMapper(builder);
}

public static ObjectMapper newObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
   return builder
            .serializationInclusion(NON_NULL)
            .failOnEmptyBeans(false)
            .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
           .featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
           .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
.build();
```

You still don't need to register the `JavaTime` module as that is still being auto-detected for you.

In theory you could combine 1 and 2 but in your case that wouldn't add much, only some code to construct the `ObjectMapper`.

```java
@Bean(name = {"objectMapper"})
@Primary
ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    return newObjectMapper(builder);
}

public static ObjectMapper newObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
   return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but What should I import to use `MapperFeature`? I got error `can't resolve symbol MapperFeature`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem while trying to enable Enum case insensitive deserialization through `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS`.

In my case switching to the builder approach was not possible due to `ObjectMapper` being previously constructed by an external source. So the only option was to modify `ObjectMapper` deserialization config directly.
Searching for alternatives to avoid deprecated API `objectMapper.enable(MappedFeature... f)` I found a workaround by...

- Getting the original `DeserializationConfig` from the `ObjectMapper` instance.
- Creating a 'copy' of the original config with
  `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS` enabled by calling
  `with(MapperFeature... features)` on the config's instance.
- Replacing the `ObjectMapper` original config with the new one through
  the setter method.

This also applies to `SerializationConfig` and it is a way of modifying configurations on an already constructed `ObjectMapper` without using deprecated APIs.

```
public void customizeMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    final DeserializationConfig originalConfig = objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig();

    final DeserializationConfig newConfig = originalConfig.with(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS);

    objectMapper.setConfig(newConfig);
}
```

**Note:** Using Jackson's builder is definitely a better solution. Consider this approach only if using the builder is not possible.